# Can't find path to plugin controller in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm messing with the Cakephp Full_Calendar plug in.
Trying to use ajax to post to the plugins main controller.

I'm pretty sure the post path would be defined in php like this....

```
$this->Html-url(array('controller'=>'FullCalendar','action'=>'index','plugin'=>'FullCalendar'));
```

I've seen and have used php within a js script before and assumed it would be this...

```
<script>
    var url = <?php echo $this->Html-url(array('controller'=>'FullCalendar','action'=>'index','plugin'=>'FullCalendar'));?>
</script>
```

Irrespective of whether that syntax is correct, the very moment I attempt to use any php within this script, the page just goes blank.

So the question is... what is the path to the plugin controller?
I've tried quite a few variations on theme....

```
Plugin/FullCalendar/index
FullCalendar.FullCalendar/index
```

Sure could use some help here.

And if anybody is available for hire that knows cakephp and fullcalendar....I'm interested.

Comment: actually, your page probably goes blank because you need to define that url as a string and add the `;` like this `var url = "<?php echo $this->Html-url(array('controller'=>'FullCalendar','action'=>'index','plugin'=>'FullCalendar'));?>";` (I know that's not your question, but I think is better to handle the urls with the pretty `Html->url` thingy)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error inside the script tag: it should be `$this->Html->url(...)` and not `$this->Html-url(...)`. You are missing a `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out and one other problem I ran into and fixed in case someone else comes across the same difficulty.

The plugin name has to be all lower case with underscores. So the 'FullCalendar' html helper link becomes...

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('Calendar'), array('controller' => 'full_calendar', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => 'full_calendar'));
```

Then, as soon as I added this plugin, all my original header menu navigation links stopped working... but only IF I was on a view that was being served by the plugin. It kept trying to insert the plugin name ahead of the controller like so...

```
mysite.com/plugin_name/controller/action
```

In order to fix it, I had to add a blank plugin argument to all my html helper links which are visible while serving a plugin view like so...

```
echo $this->Html->link(__('link'), array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action', 'plugin' => ''));
```

I don't know if this is proper cake syntax, but it works.
Hope this helps someone.